# what does Whitney sum of vector bundles correspond to in the k-theory KO?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, geometric-topology, topological-k-theory

Let $X$ be a $CW$-complex and $\text{Vect}^n(X)$  the collection of $n$-dimensional real vector bundles over $X$. Let 
$$
\text{Vect}^*(X)=\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty \text{Vect}^n(X)
$$
with addition
\begin{eqnarray*}
\oplus:  \text{Vect}^m(X)\times\text{Vect}^n(X)&\longrightarrow& \text{Vect}^{m+n}(X),\\
(\xi,\eta)&\longmapsto&\xi\oplus\eta
\end{eqnarray*}
and multiplication
\begin{eqnarray*}
\otimes:  \text{Vect}^m(X)\times\text{Vect}^n(X)&\longrightarrow& \text{Vect}^{mn}(X),\\
(\xi,\eta)&\longmapsto&\xi\otimes\eta
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\oplus$ denotes the Whitney sum and $\otimes$ the tensor product. Then $KO(X)$, the K-theory of $X$, can be identified with the group completion of $(\text{Vect}(X),\oplus)$.

On the other hand, by the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence, 
$$
E_2^{p,q}=H^p(X;KO^q(*))
$$ 
converges to the generalized cohomology theory $KO(X)=\oplus_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}KO^n(X)$. The generalized cohomology theory has addition $+$ and cup-product $\smile$.

**Question.**

(1). What does $\text{Vect}^1(X)$ correspond to in $KO(X)$? Does $\text{Vect}^n(X)$ correspond to $KO^n(X)$?

(2).  What does $\oplus$ correspond to in $KO(X)$? With the addition $\oplus$, does the monoid $(\text{Vect}^*(X),\oplus)$ isomorphic  to $(KO^n(X)\mid _{n\geq 0},+)$?

(3).  With the addition $\oplus$ and multiplication $\otimes$, does the monoid with multiplication $(\text{Vect}^*(X),\oplus,\otimes)$ isomorphic to $(KO^n(X)\mid _{n\geq 0},+,\smile)$ (I think it is wrong)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. Vector bundles all land in $KO^0(X)$.
2. Direct sum corresponds to addition (again, all happening in $KO^0$).
3. Tensor product corresponds to multiplication.

Comment: Thanks! Does the $KO^0$ refer to the graded module of generalized cohomology of dimension zero?

Comment: Yes. For $n \neq 0$ the description of $KO^n$ is more complicated than just vector bundles.